# Is there a Apache cordova pluggin for Microsoft Band?

Tags: cordova, microsoft-band

Is there a Apache cordova pluggin for Microsoft Band ? I'm trying to receive the sensor values from Microsoft Band in a corodva app.

Regards,
Sowmyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not yet on npm [this plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugin-msband) looks interesting. You can find some slides on how to add it to your project and use it [here](http://purplecabbage.github.io/slides/PGMeetupApr2015/index.html#/).

Quick research showed there are other plugins out there like [this one](https://github.com/dkundel/band-cordova) but checking out the repo showed there are no supported platforms yet.